# Kotlin overloading operator index with assign other than set

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading

In Kotlin, is it possible to overload the following operation to `x: X`?

```
x[i] += j
```

Currently, I can only see an indirect way, like defining some `X.get` that returns an object of type `XAtIndex` with a reference to the original, then defining `XAtIndex.plugAssign` that modifies the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a `+=` that mutates an object instead of changing what is stored in a variable, you must implement `plusAssign` on the type of the object returned by `get()`. An example of this in the standard library is `MutableList.plusAssign()`.

If you want the more traditional behavior of reassigning the value held at an index after creating a modified copy, your class should have matching `get` and `set` operator functions. Then you can implement a `plus` function on whatever is the type of the `get`/`set` (if it doesn't have one). When `+=` is used, it will use the getter and setter operator functions along with the `plus` operator of the type returned by `get`. Example:

```
class Foo {
    private var thing1: String = "Hello"
    private var thing2: String = "World"

    operator fun get(thing: Int) = when (thing) {
        1 -> thing1
        2 -> thing2
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }.also { println("get") }

    operator fun set(thing: Int, value: String) {
        when (thing) {
            1 -> thing1 = value
            2 -> thing2 = value
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
        println("set")
    }

    override fun toString(): String ="Foo(thing1='$thing1', thing2='$thing2')"

}

fun main() {
    val foo = Foo()
    foo[1] += "!!!"
    println(foo)
}
```

Comment: `When += is used, it will use the getter and setter operator functions along with the plus operator of the type returned by get` Thank you, I was under the mistaken impression it would only call `plusAssign`. That solves everything.

Comment: plusAssign() is used if it’s available. But it falls back to the traditional behavior when it’s not. I think it’s kind of confusing that they even let you create plusAssign and have it behave differently than `+=` is usually expected to.